# I created delete user account button in my project but am unable to delete messages a deleted user left for other users

Tags: php, codeigniter

When a user is in their account and clicks 'delete account' its supposed to delete the user, along with messages they left for users, and also stop showing as a friend to other users. I have 2 of these working but messages still appear for another user if they log in. I have a function already created that a user can use to delete messages from friends, and I've tried to implement this into a new function so it will delete messages, but from specific friends. Here is the original deleteMsg which will delete all the fields(message_id, from, to, message) so the message will be deleted in the messages database. This function appears in my messages model:

```
function deleteMsg($message_id)
 {

$this->db->where(array('message_id' => $message_id));
$this->db->delete('messages');

 }
```

Here is the function I'm trying to implement so that when the delete account is called it will delete all messages left by this now deleted user on other user's homepages. It also appears in my model:

```
  function deleteAccountMsg($message_id, $from)
  {
$delAcctMsg = $this->db->select('*')->from('messages')->where('message_id', $message_id)->where('from', $from);
$delete = $this->db->delete('messages', $delAcctMsg);

    }
```

Finally, here is the DeleteUserAccount function in my controller that is supposed to grab everything associated with the user and delete it :

```
 function Deleteuseraccount()
 {
    parent::__construct();

    $this->load->model("membership");
    $this->load->model("friends");
    $this->load->model("messages");


    $username = $this->session->userdata('username');
    $this->membership->deleteUser($username);
    $this->friends->deleteMemberFriend($username, $friendname);
    $this->messages-> deleteAccountMsg($message_id, $from);// this is the function I'm calling that isn't deleting the associate messages from the deleted user
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('start');
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$this->db->select('*')->from('messages')->where('from', $username)->or_where('to', $username);

This actually solved this issue

Comment: Just a note (as indicated above) that doing a "select" before the "delete" is both inefficient and not advised. Firstly, you are making two calls when one would do. Secondly, as unlikely as it may sound, a user may add an entry between the select and the delete - this record will then be orphaned.

Comment: Ok thanks for pointing this out - would you suggest this?                  $this->db->delete('*')->from('profileimages')->where('user', $username);

Answer (score 0):

You are deleting (by selecting) only one message at a time. You need ot remove the message id restrictions

```
$delAcctMsg = $this->db->select('*')->from('messages')->where('from', $from);
$delete = $this->db->delete('messages', $delAcctMsg);
```

---

A few notes

1) Write in pseudo SQL first

You can work out what you want to do by spelling it out in PHP

```
SELECT *
FROM messages
WHERE from=$from
```

This then gives you the chains you need for your SQL model.

2) Why `SELECT *` when you you only need to select message_id?

3) Why do the `SELECT` at all when you can just to the delete? Saves network traffic, processing and mySQL calls.

```
$delete = $this->db->delete('messages')->where('from', $from);
```

4) If you want to adapt the previous function, you could break into bits. Something like

```
// (Untested - try it first on test data)
$this->db->where('from', $from);
if ($message_id) {
    $this->db->where('message_id', $message_id);
}
$this->db->delete('messages');
```

Comment: Hi Robbie, thanks for that. I tried this line in my deleteAccountMsg function:$delete = $this->db->delete('messages')->where('message_id', $message_id)->where('from', $from); But then I got 2 errors. the first one was a php error was encountered: Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal offset type . I also got a database error occurred: Deletes are not allowed unless they contain a "where" or "like" clause. Haven't I just included 2 wheres in my sql delete statement??

Comment: thanks again - I delete a user's account now and it ends up deleting all messages across the board. While there is now some functioanlity and I appreciate this, how can I get the deleteAccountMsg to just delete messages belonging to the username of the person whose account is deleted? If you need further explaining please let me know..

Comment: Break down into the last example then. There's a decent enough set of examples here: http://www.phpexpertsforum.com/deleting-data-in-codeigniter-t2009.html (easier than the CI documentation). Yes - you have two WHEREs in your question [message_id AND from] which is causing the problem when trying to delete ALL records from one user as you only need the one WHERE [from]

Comment: Ok thanks - Ive tried just using the from but same thing - I'm thinking is there anyway I can reference the specific friend name and refer to the friend in my friends database from within the sql statement....

Comment: Yes, there is. And given the code in the question, I've given you the answer. If that's not it (e.g. "from" is actually a user _id and not a name etc), then there's more you need to reveal if you can't work it out from this. Sorry - I can only help based off your question.

Comment: Hi Robbie thanks for all your help but I managed to do this by using or_where :   $this->db->select('*')->from('messages')->where('from', $username)->or_where('to', $username);

Comment: And where did the "to" come from? You really need to put everything in your question if you want people to help.

Comment: it covers who the message was to in case any other user sent them, the deleted user, a message